# Cloud Foundry Django app `cf push` logs the error `port 5432 failed: Connection refused`

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, cloud-foundry

I am deploying a basic Django app with Cloud Foundry. The app appears to be unable to connect to or authenticate with the database.

I encounter the error after I run the `cf push -f manifest.yml` command. It returns `Start unsuccessful` and suggests I look at the logs with the `cf logs app-name-1 --recent` command. The logs contain this error:

```
ERR django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "server-name.region-name.rds.amazonaws.com" (ip.redacted), port 5432 failed: Connection refused
ERR Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

The app's repo contains a `manifest.yml` that specifies an application name `app-name-1` and a service `service-name-psql-db`.

This app exists, as you can see from the output of the `cf apps` command:

```
Getting apps in org org-name / space space-name as user-name..

name         requested state   processes   routes
app-name-1   started           web:0/1     app-name-1.app.domain.com
```

Further, the app is hooked up to a database service as you can see from the output of the `cf services` command:

```
Getting services in org org-name / space space-name as user-name...

name                   service   plan         bound apps   last operation     broker        upgrade available
service-name-psql-db   aws-rds   micro-psql   app-name-1   update succeeded   aws-broker
```

The credentials I am trying to use to connect to the database seem correct to me. As I understand it, these two facts should line up the credentials needed to authenticate:

- The return of `cf env app-name-1` contains a key named `aws-rds` which further contains `db_name`, `password`, `username`, `port`, etc., with plausible-looking values
- These values match the output of `cf service-key service-name-psql-db testkey`

Is this an authentication problem? Or is the database service not being located at all? The error is so generic I'm having a hard time coming up with next steps.

Comment: It sounds like you are almost there. The binding is good, that's passing the info/creds to your app, the app is reading those and attempting to make a connection. The problem seems to be that you just don't have network access to the database. It's failing to setup a TCP connection. If your IP/port are correct, then you'd want to look at your security groups, to see they permit outgoing traffic to that IP. You may need to talk to your CF Operator team about that though, that requires admin access to change. Beyond that, the IP needs to be routable and not blocked by firewalls on your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was about security groups and egress. Commenter [@daniel-mikusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1585136/daniel-mikusa) was on the right track: I had to work with my CF operators to find  how to set an egress appropriate for trusted local networks. [This Cloud.gov documentation](https://cloud.gov/docs/management/space-egress/) helped with my particular CF operators. (Your org may differ, reader.)